# Content-script code stops working when URL changes from .com to .com/#/xxx

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

First, I'm going to explain what I want and then what I have tried.

I'm trying to create an extension that auto-fill forms and selection inputs.

The webpage is https://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/ and when you have done the first form and go to the next part the webpage changes to https://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/#/terrain and you do a new form and the next url is https://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/#/roof and so on.

I can see that I don't reload the page when I look in network -> Doc I'm still on the same https://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/.

But the code stops working as fast as it changes the URL to /#/xxx

## manifest.json

```
{
"name": "xxx",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "...",
"manifest_version": 3,
"author": ",xxx",
"action":{
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "xxx"
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/#/canvas*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "js": ["scripts/adress.js"],
      "matches": [
        "*://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

}

## adress.js

```
console.log("./scripts/adress.js");

const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
console.log(mutations);
try {
    var shadowRoot = document.querySelector('div > div').shadowRoot;
    // console.log(shadowRoot);

    // console.log("This is now logged");
    // check if the element exists
    // if (document.querySelector('div > div').shadowRoot) {
    //     var adress = shadowRoot.querySelector('div > div > div.sc-hKgILt.FbHhJ > div:nth-child(4) > div > input');
    //     var header = shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > div.sc-hKgILt.FbHhJ > h2")
    //     var tesrt = document.querySelector("#app > div").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > div > div.sc-hKgILt.FbHhJ > h2")
        
    //     try {
    //         if (adress) {
    //             // alert("Adress")
    //             adress.value = "Södra Lundavägen 24"
    //         }

    //         if (header) {
    //             // console.log("There is a header");
    //             console.log(header.textContent);
    //         }
    //     } catch (error) {
    //         console.log(error);
    //     }

    //     // display an alert message
    //     // window.alert('Hello World');
    // }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}

});

// configure and start the observer
const observerConfig = { childList: true, subtree: true };

observer.observe(document.body, observerConfig);
```

I've commented out part of the code when debugging.

But even here I don't log the "mutations" when the URL changes.

Don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I don't know if it's the observer that breaks the loging or the manifest or whats going on.

Comment: 1) Content scripts `matches` don't support `#` because there's no navigation: the URL is simply faked via `window.history` but the page document stays the same. You need to match the entire site in `matches` and then detect fake navigation by using MutationObserver or the new [navigation.onnavigate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation/navigate_event) event. 2) The page may be using an iframe for its content. Use devtools to inspect it.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you mean I just need to use solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/* or need to putt all the variants under the same match like 

"matches": [
        "*://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/*",
         "*://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/#/xxxx*",
         "*://solpanelsfasten.welandstal.com/#/xxxxxxxx*"
      ]


* should fix that with the main page so I think its just the MutationObserver thats not configuerd corretly in my case.

Comment: Use `/*` for all your scripts. Investigate what happens in devtools. In addition to the possibility of an iframe, the page may replace `document.body` so you may want to observe `document`.